# textbox in Mapoverlay/ textbox in custom view to display on a map

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am kind of new to IOS app development. I have a map view and when a user taps on the MKMapView, i want to pop a text box there so that user can tag the place. I figured out the part on how to handle tap events on map. But I couldn't really understand how to get the textbox up there on map. I think I should use overlays, but I am not sure how to put a text box in an overlay. Can someone please give me sample code to put textbox in overlay?

Here is my code which handles tap events and this overlay display might have to go in the if loop.

```
-(void)handleTapOnMap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender 
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        NSLog(@"Tapped on the map");
        return;
    }
    else {

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add custom overlays you can see this [project on overlays](https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo) on github

Or if you want to add the overlay yourself you will have to create a custom view and use the delegate method :

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay
    {
    yourOverLayView *view = [[[yourOverLayView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];

    return view;
    }
```

You can also go through the [mkmapview tutorial](http://shawnsbits.com/blog/2011/04/04/adding-polygon-map-overlays/) :

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it doesn't really help me with creating text box right? From IOS documentation, i figured out how to create custom shapes like circles/squares. but using inbuilt textbox is something i couldn't figure out.